# Automatically run ispell on magit COMMIT_MSG buffer

Tags: magit, ispell

I make lots of spelling errors when constructing my commit message.
It would be cool if I could add a hook to magit such that when I execute
`C-c C-c`, it would run ispell before completing the commit message.

I can't figure out how to hack it, but I'm wondering if anyone else has tried to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to hack anything - just add `git-commit-turn-on-flyspell` to `git-commit-setup-hook`. If you use the Custom interface to do so, then that is even one of the suggested functions for that hook.

Comment: TIL about flyspell.  This helps me out a lot, I'm adding it to all my modes.

Answer (score 0):

Add `(add-hook 'git-commit-setup-hook 'git-commit-turn-on-flyspell)` line
to the emacs config file.